# Why was this flag declined?

Tags: discussion, support, etiquette, declined-flags, code-of-conduct

> **Who cares for Spitzer here**.... – Rakesh Joshi [Mar 26 at 18:47](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38811/was-vishnu-sahasranama-not-a-part-of-anusasana-parva-of-mahabharata-but-a-late#comment124573_38811)
>
> unfriendly or unkind – sv.   Mar 27 at 20:48   **declined**  (10 hours ago)

I'm not sure why the comment which clearly breaks the SE [Code of Conduct](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct) was declined.

> #### Unacceptable Behavior
>
> **No subtle put-downs** or unfriendly language.
>
> Even if you don’t intend it, this can have a negative impact on others.

Does this mean users who don't like certain gurus/acharyas/scholars are now free to post similar comments under questions/answers citing them?

Comment: oh! Actually we have three options on a falg decline, edit and delete. By mistake I pressed on decline instead of delete. The comment has been removed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting [a comment](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1879/why-was-this-flag-declined/1897#comment8679_1879) into answer,

> oh! Actually we have three options on a falg decline, edit and delete. By mistake I pressed on decline instead of delete. The comment has been removed now. – Pandya♦ Mar 31 at 13:18